# Get raw, unformatted, unmasked text from JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I have a `JFormattedTextField` that masks a phone number in the format:

```
 (###) ###-####
```

I need to retrieve the unformatted, raw `##########` to store in a database.

Currently, I am using `.getText().replaceAll("\\)", "").replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("-", "").replaceAll(" ", "")`, but this just seems like it should be easier.

Is there a way to get the unmasked, unformatted, raw input from a `JFormattedTextField`?

Here's the [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    final JFormattedTextField phone = new JFormattedTextField();
    try {
        phone.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter("(###) ###-####")));
    } catch(ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    phone.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, phone.getPreferredSize().height));
    final JButton button = new JButton("Get Text");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(phone.getText().replaceAll("\\)", "").replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("-", "").replaceAll(" ", ""));
        }
    });
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(phone);
    panel.add(button);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do not use `MaskFormatter`:

```
    maskF = new MaskFormatter("(###) ###-####");
    maskF.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters ( false );  
    askF.setOverwriteMode ( true );  
    maskF.setValidCharacters ( "0123456789" );  

    fTextField  = new JFormattedTextField(maskF);           
    fTextField.addPropertyChangeListener("value", this);

     //...

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == fTextField) {

            if(fTextField.getValue() != null){
                System.out.println((fTextField.getValue()));
            } 
        }    
    }
```

Type `(123) 456-7890` and press Enter. The output will be

```
1234567890
```

Generally since the mask is not completed , the `fTextField.getValue()` returns `null`

**full code**

```
public class Main implements PropertyChangeListener {

    private JFormattedTextField fTextField;
    private MaskFormatter maskF ;

      public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {              
          new Main().init(); 
      }

    private void init() throws ParseException {
           JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Container content = f.getContentPane();
            content.setLayout(new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));


            maskF = new MaskFormatter("(###) ###-####");
            maskF.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters ( false );  
            maskF.setOverwriteMode ( true );  
            maskF.setValidCharacters ( "0123456789" );  

            fTextField  = new JFormattedTextField(maskF);           
            fTextField.addPropertyChangeListener("value", this);
            content.add(fTextField );
            f.setSize(300, 100);
            f.setVisible(true);        
    }


    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == fTextField) {

            if(fTextField.getValue() != null){
                System.out.println((fTextField.getValue()));
            } 
        }    
    }
    }
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how is that going to help the OP get the text unmasked?

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Sorry, I wrote direction only. Anyways updated my question

Answer (score 1):

You can use a character class to clean up the code `"[\\s()-]"`

```
System.out.println(phone.getText().replaceAll("[\\s()-]", ""));
```

Answer (score -2):

Create auxiliary variables to put the original value, and store the value in the auxiliary variable to database. JFormattedTextField just to display the changed value of the format.